# Export Images in Excel File via NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I have a .xlsx file with 1100+ images in 1 column, and different data in the other columns. I need to export the images to a folder and renamed after a row in the sheet. Is there any way to do with Node.js?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest saving the excel file as a webpage (stores all the images in a separate folder), steps are described in the following article,

https://www.excelhowto.com/how-to-quickly-extract-pictures-from-an-excel-file/

Then you can save the same excel file as CSV, use node.js to read in the CSV and images then output to the correct folder/filename.